# Change Value of the particular column in grid using keyboard space button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I posted my sample code below. In that I want to change the Value of Attendance column using keyboard button(Space button). I'm searching to get "sample code/any clues" in google, till now I get any sample one. So please help me/advise me to solve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head lang="en">



    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title>Custom Plunker</title>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>



<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);


    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", attendance: "L", age: 50},

                 {name: "Tiancum", attendance: "A", age: 43},

                 {name: "Jacob", attendance: "P", age: 27},

                 {name: "Nephi", attendance: "E", age: 29},

                 {name: "Enos", attendance: "L", age: 34}];


    $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{field:'name', displayName:'Name'}, {field:'attendance',          displayName:'Attendance', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="ChangeValue(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>'},
 {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}],
    showFooter: true,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    multiSelect: false,


 };
$scope.ChangeValue = function(row) {

    if(row.entity.attendance === 'L') {
        row.entity.attendance = 'P';
    } else if(row.entity.attendance === 'P') {
        row.entity.attendance = 'A';
    } else if(row.entity.attendance === 'A') {
        row.entity.attendance = 'E';
    } else {
        row.entity.attendance = 'L';
    }


}

    });

   </script>

</head>



<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">


    <div ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>


</body>
```

When I select any cell in column Attendance, then I should be able to change that value using keyboard "space" button.

Thanks:
Ramakrishna K.C

Comment: check out ui-keypress from angular-ui

Comment: No pal.. I tried, its not working. I mean, That whole column values are not displaying itself, when I use ui-keypress keyword in celltemplate.